# CMenu replace item with submenu

Tags: mfc, submenu, cmenu

I have a MFC CMenu with some items. I would like to convert or replace a single menu item with a sub-menu, with additional menu items. Is there an easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

The [`CMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d0s49351.aspx) class provides the class member [`CMenu::SetMenuItemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wbec0428.aspx) to modify an existing menu item by passing it a properly initialized [`MENUITEMINFO` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms647578.aspx).

To replace a menu item with a pop-up menu (sub menu) you have to perform 3 steps.

### 1. Create a new pop-up menu

You can either create the menu dynamically by calling [`CMenu::CreatePopupMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/43a4d589.aspx) and populate it with [`CMenu::InsertMenuItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9e0xs4bc.aspx) or load an existing pop-up menu from a resource using [`CMenu::LoadMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/177ay1x0.aspx):

```
CMenu MyMenu;
MyMenu.CreatePopupMenu();
MENUITEMINFO mii = { 0 };
mii.cbSize = sizeof( MENUITEMINFO );
mii.fMask = MIIM_ID | MIIM_STRING;
mii.wID = IDM_MY_MENU_ITEM1;   // #define this in your Resource.h file
mii.dwTypeData = _T( "Menu Item 1" );
MyMenu.InsertMenuItem( 0, &mii, TRUE );
```

### 2. Initialize a `MENUITEMINFO` structure

```
MENUITEMINFO miiNew = { 0 };
miiNew.cbSize = sizeof( MENUITEMINFO );
miiNew.fMask = MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_STRING;
miiNew.hSubMenu = MyMenu.Detach();   // Detach() to keep the pop-up menu alive
                                     // when MyMenu goes out of scope
miiNew.dwTypeData = _T( "Some text" );
```

### 3. Replace existing menu item

```
MyMainMenu.SetMenuItemInfo( IDM_ITEM_TO_BE_REPLACED,
                            &miiNew,
                            FALSE );
DrawMenuBar( hWnd );
```

The call to [`DrawMenuBar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms647633.aspx) is required whenever a window's menu is modified.

Comment: what is 'MyMainMenu' ? Should we use 'LoadMenu()' and load our main menu into it? If yes, then can't we load the main menu into 'MyMenu' variable instead of 'CreatePopupMenu()'?

Comment: @HariRam: `MyMainMenu` is a window's main menu. It doesn't matter, whether this is the result of a call to `LoadMenu()`, or created dynamically. You can create `MyMenu` from a resource as well, as long as the argument to `LoadMenu()` is a submenu. A common solution is to create a menu in the resource editor, with dummy entries for the main menu bar, adding submenus as needed.